# SQL - How to create a partition on multiple keys

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, filegroup

We have following two columns in table  schema.

1. ClientID INT
2. TransactionDate  Date

Currently, this table is partitioned based on TransactionDate. But we also want to partition on ClientID and TransactionDate.  Is it possible in SQL Server 2016 ?

If not then can we insert data into this table into different files-groups based on the ClientID.  (We are going to create different file-groups by clientid. We have fixed 5 clientid in the database)

Answer (score 0):

Don't think SQL server supports multiple partition keys as of yet at the table level.
You can create a partitioned index(different partition scheme from the table) on ClientID column with partition key as ClientID.